# Saving text in UITextView Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a To-Do App on IOS Platform Swift 3
I am trying to save note in UITextView so when i hit back or terminate application the data is saved.

StoryBoard Have a UITextView and a save button at the navigation bar
How to make user enter his text in UITextView and save it

```
class Details: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{

// MARK: - IB
@IBOutlet weak var noteText: UITextView!
@IBAction func addNote(_ sender: UIButton) {

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
   let addNote = Note(context: context)
    addNote.details = noteText.text!

    //Saving
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

}

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var Notes: [Note] = []

func getData() {
    do {
        Notes = try context.fetch(Note.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let MyIcon = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "037_Pen"))
    self.navigationItem.titleView = MyIcon
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Any idea how to display it ?
Created `Entity` called `Note` with `Attribute` `details` of type `String`

Comment: So whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: You need to pick some form of persistence mechanism; Core Data, a text file, a plist. and save your data and load it when you app starts

Comment: I tried to use Core Data but wasn't able to display them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dealing with data in iOS application

---

If you want to save your data inside application then you need to do something more inside your application for data saving purpose. This way you can save data inside application weather terminate application it will show your saved data and fetch again.

1.) For Short Date save can use UserDefaults

2.) By using [SQLite](http://www.appcoda.com/fmdb-sqlite-database/)

3.) By Using [Coredata](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial)

4.) By Using [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/), For more details check [Example.](https://medium.com/@skoli/using-realm-and-charts-with-swift-3-in-ios-10-40c42e3838c0#.hvrbn3358)

Comment: Yes can use Realm also but basic level its all sufficient. @takethefake

Comment: Sounds like CordData, SQLite, Realm are overkill - maybe just writing to a file?

Comment: Not like that its holding your data contains in a proper way and for saving files like images and documents, we are using [DocumentDirectory.](https://thatthinginswift.com/writing-documents-directory-swift/) @Ashley Mills

Answer (score 0):

You need to create database to save the text value every time as per your requirement.

You can create the database by using any one of the below :

1. `Core data`[Get tutorial from here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)
2. `SQLite` [Get tutorial from here](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/)

Save your text data by using anyone these and then fetch the data and assign at the UI.